# Dynamic number of list is showing errorin django pagination?

Tags: python, django

Code listing:

```
list = request.GET.get('list')
paginator = Paginator(categories_list, list)
```

During run raise exception:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Sorry, this question's a bit too short with not enough information to help. Can you better lay out what you were trying to do, the code you were using, and the result, error, etc that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

`list = request.GET.get('list')` gives the result of `None` and then, when instantiating `Paginator`, you get this exception.
Second argement of [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/paginator/#paginator-class) could not be `None`.

Try to setup a default value if `list` query parameter is not provided:

```
list = request.GET.get('list', 10)
```